# MySQL Unique and NULL Index Advice

Tags: mysql, indexing, database-design, unique-constraint, unique-index

I have an unique index requirement that I can't figure out.

Three columns in my table

```
Code (VarChar)  |  User(Int - Nullable)  |  Item(Int - Nullable)
```

I set up an unique index on `Code AND User` and another on `Code AND Item`

This means we cannot have at any point more than one code referring to the same `user` if `item` is `NULL` and we cannot have more than one code referring to the same `item` if `user` is `NULL`

But I have a third case...

I want to be able to have a code relating to a User AND and Item which may already exist for EITHER the same Item or User. But I can't do this because it will clash with one of the indexes above.

So, given the unique indexes described above, I also want it to be possible to insert these records

```
Code (VarChar)  |  User(Int - Nullable)  |  Item(Int - Nullable)  
   12345678     |        NULL            |          1  
   12345678     |        1               |         NULL
   12345678     |        2               |          1     ** This row clashes on ITEM **
```

Is this possible or am I doing something stupid again!?

Answer (score 0):

Right - the answer seems to just be "don't use `NULL`"

So, if I use a 0 instead of `NULL` where there is no `Item` or `User` data required, I can have the unique constraints I need!